# why only 5 tags per question?

Tags: discussion, questions, tagging

after adding the database engine, for example `sql-server` and then adding the version for example `sql-server-2016` there are only 3 extra tags you can add to a question.

often when asking questions I have to filter and leave some related tags out.

is the limitation of 5 tags a site feature? If it can be changed what would be the process?

Comment: Related: [What are the reasons behind having a maximum of 5 tags per question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69201/what-are-the-reasons-behind-having-a-maximum-of-5-tags-per-question) (a duplicate actually, since the question is fundamentally the same, but given how old that one is, it might make sense to revisit it)

Comment: I feel like DBA.SE might be a good candidate to increase that limit (if that is possible). Along marcello's line of thinking, I could easily have a question about upgrades that is relevant for `sql-server-2012`, `sql-server-2016`, and `sql-server` which leaves me with only 2 tags for the more specific issue. I think getting the versions & generic product tag is important in this case, so maybe 7-8 would be more appropriate? Only [~13k posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/684789/dba-se-posts-with-4-tags) out of 133k have 4 or more tags on them so abuse doesn't seem to be a big issue.

Comment: @JohnM Seems like that example shouldn't have [tag:sql-server], and instead have just [tag:sql-server-2016] and [tag:sql-server-2012], to both of which [tag:sql-server] should be marked `related`

Comment: Based on the description of the `sql-server` tag it seems fair to expect it to be used in conjunction with a version tag: "All versions of Microsoft SQL Server (not MySQL). Please also add a version-specific tag like sql-server-2016 if that is relevant to the question." Not that that can't be changed, but I do think there is value in having the generic tag for search visibility.

Comment: Additional benefit for the generic tag is when usage for favorite or ignore tags - this makes it easier to blanket favorite or ignore all MSSQL questions with a single tag instead of managing variations.